# AsyncTimeoutAttribute is not working with Controller Actions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

We tried to use the following code to increase request timeout for our backup process which runs on `IIS` and `ASP.NET MVC`:

```
[AsyncTimeout(79200000)]
public async Task<ActionResult> DailyBackup(Guid secret)
{
    HttpContext.Server.ScriptTimeout = 22*3600;
    await Backups.Create();
    return null;
}
```

However, this didn't change the timeout and after a short period of time, `ASP.NET MVC` returns us an empty page and `await Backups.Create()` is continue to run separately in background.

What should we do in order to increase timeout for certain actions without changing our `Web.Config` file?